# Where do I begin learning to program bots?

Tags: python, c, linux, ubuntu, automation

I don't know what they're called but I want to learn to program bots that perform tasks within a game or software. But I have no idea how to even make a program that does stuff on other programs/software/games. Are their any good books on the subject?

If it makes a difference I'm using a Linux OS. I know Python and I began learning C recently.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest starting with a concrete goal (for example, "I want to build a minesweeper bot"). This way you'll have your energy focused. :-)

Comment: Maybe sign up for this online class: https://www.ai-class.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many tools for sending artificial input.  My [favorite one](http://www.autohotkey.com/) only works on Windows.

For the cross platform, including Linux, there is a library called [autopy](http://www.autopy.org/).  As you can guess, it's a Python library and it allows you to access your keyboard and mouse through Python objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automate requests and parsing, Python has packages [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) (specifically for parsing).

Comment: The OP wrote, "perform tasks within a game or software."